# Proof that feasible region of linear program is exactly one convex region

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I have the following linear program:
$$\text{max b}\\\ \text{subject to} \quad \vec{x} \cdot \vec{r}_j \geq b \quad \forall j \quad \text{with} \quad x_i \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^N x_i=1,$$
where $\vec{x}$ and $b$ must be determined, the $\vec{r}_j \in \mathbb{R}^N$ are known.

How can I prove that the feasible region is exactly one (maybe infinite) convex region?

In contrast to standard linear programs, the $x_i$ are allowed to be negative, but that should not change whether the feasible region is exactly one convex region, right?

Since the constraints in a linear program are linear, the allowed region is exactly one convex body. Additionally the allowed solution has to lie on the infinitely large expansion of the simplex ($x_i \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^N x_i=1$), which is convex as well.

So the intersection must be exactly one convex region, right?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: It is a linear program, whose feasible set, as you noticed, is an intersection of convex sets, hence convex.There is no difference between the geometry of linear programs in one standard form or another.

Comment: Yes. To put it in other words you say you have an intersection of convex sets, so it is convex.

Comment: Any convex set is quite obviously connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two arbitrary feasible solutions, and let $\alpha \in [0,1]$.  Now show that the solution $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$ is feasible.

Comment: Yes, you can explain it in words by appealing to a theorem that linear implies convex. But it is probably more instructive to use linearity to explicitly show that the new solution satisfies the constraints.  Substitute the solution into each constraint, and use feasibility of $x$ and $y$ to show that the constraint is satisfied.

Comment: The same proof I'm suggesting to show convexity also shows connectedness: for every feasible two points, the line segment joining them is feasible.